# jQuery alternate row CSS for parent table only

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I've got a form with a lot of hidden elements formatted with tables.  I need to be able to re-alternate the table row colors with CSS after a hidden element is shown.  I've gotten the this to work with jQuery, however, when re-adding the CSS class it is also alternating classes for nested tables as well.  What command would keep this from happening?  Code example below:

```
<table id='parent-table'>
    <tr class='form_odd_row'>
        <td><label for='f1'>On/Off</label></td>
        <td><table id='chkbox-table'>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><input type='radio' name='ck' value='1' id='ck1'> On</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><input type='radio' name='ck' value='2' id='ck2'> Off</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><input type='radio' name='ck' value='3' id='ck3'> N/A</td>
                </tr>    
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='form_even_row'>
        <td><label for='n1'>Name</label></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='name' value=''></td>
    </tr>
    <tr  class='form_odd_row' id='hidden-row'>
        <td><label for='h'>Address</label></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='address' value=''></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery -

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('input:radio[name="ck"]').change(function(){ 
            if($("#ck3").is(":checked")){ 
                $("#hidden-row").show(); 
            } else { 
                $("#hidden-row").hide(); 
            } 
            $("#parent-table tr").removeClass('form_odd_row'); 
            $("#parent-table tr").removeClass('form_even_row'); 
            $("#parent-table tr:odd").addClass("form_odd_row"); 
            $("#parent-table tr:even").addClass("form_even_row"); 
        }) 
    }); 
</script>
```

What is happening is the table which has the checkboxes are getting alternating rows along with the parent table.  How do you tell jQuery to only change rows on the parent table?

Answer (score 2):

#### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hupug/2/edit)

just use a direct child selector like this:

```
$("#parent-table > tr").removeClass('form_odd_row'); 
$("#parent-table > tr").removeClass('form_even_row'); 
$("#parent-table > tr:odd").addClass("form_odd_row"); 
$("#parent-table > tr:even").addClass("form_even_row");
```

Comment: Would you have any idea why neither this or Jay's answer will neither work?  The demos both work but neither work on my site.  I'm including jquery 1.10.2 in the page header from googleapis.com.  The original code works, but If I add the direct child selector it quits working.

Comment: does your html look exactly like what you posted? maybe you wrapped the <tr> with <tbody> or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it -

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('input:radio[name="ck"]').change(function(){ 
        if($("#ck3").is(":checked")){ 
            $("#hidden-row").show(); 
        } else { 
            $("#hidden-row").hide(); 
        } 
        $(this).parent('table tr').removeClass('form_odd_row'); 
        $(this).parent('table tr').removeClass('form_even_row'); 
        $(this).parent('table tr:odd').addClass("form_odd_row"); 
        $(this).parent('table tr:even').addClass("form_even_row"); 
    }) 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W35Y7/1/